# Binding for attribute Angular 2 doesn't update associated input with bound id

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-components

I have a checkbox within my component with bindings like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" [name]="name" [id]="id" /><label [htmlFor]="id"></label>
```

When the component loads I can inspect the element and find that the values passed to those inputs are bound, but when I click the label the checkbox doesn't get checked.

I've also tried it like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" [attr.name]="name" [attr.id]="id" /><label [attr.for]="id"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="{{name}}" id="{{id}} /><label [attr.for]="id"></label>
```

And combinations thereof.  They all produce the same effect, data is bound, checkbox not checked.

Here is my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  inputs: ['name', 'id'],
  selector: 'my-checkbox',
  templateUrl: 'app/form/input/checkbox.component.html'
})

export class CheckboxComponent {}
```

And the html where it's used:

```
<my-checkbox name="test-name" id="test-id"></my-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `id` as input name, you get your component as dom-element with this id. It adds same id to the checkbox, and `for` of the label. But when you have multiple elements with same id, label refers to first of them. In your case it refers you component instead of `input`.

**Just rename input parameter.**

By the way, it would've be right to declare corresponding field in ts class.

http://plnkr.co/edit/JazXV3Oi91hSBTdVlBHh?p=preview

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <my-checkbox-broken id="test-id-1"></my-checkbox-broken><br>
      <my-checkbox-broken [id]="'test-id-2'"></my-checkbox-broken> can work too<br>
      <my-checkbox-working chkId="test-id-3"></my-checkbox-working><br>
      <output></output>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
}

@Component({
  inputs: ['id'],
  selector: 'my-checkbox-broken',
  template: '<input type="checkbox" [id]="id" /><label [htmlFor]="id">Broken :(</label>'
})
export class CheckboxComponent_Broken {
  id: string;
}

@Component({
  inputs: ['chkId'],
  selector: 'my-checkbox-working',
  template: '<input type="checkbox" [id]="chkId" /><label [htmlFor]="chkId">Working!</label>'
})
export class CheckboxComponent_Working {
  chkId: string;
}

document.addEventListener('click', ({ target: { htmlFor: id } }) => {
  if (id) {
    document.querySelector('output').textContent = id + " is " + document.getElementById(id).tagName;
  }
})
```

Comment: So simple. Thank you for the response. :)

Comment: @JohnHalbert, it was a nice question :) By the way, accept the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

```
<my-checkbox [name]="'test-name'" [id]="'test-id'"></my-checkbox>
<my-checkbox name="test-name" [id]="'test-id'"></my-checkbox>
```

You need to pass values as strings, `[property]="experession"`, and for expressions to evaluate to string it has to be in quotes `'test-name'`.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fvYuBXWJ16BrkytbXCEl)

Comment: This doesn't quite solve the problem.  The values for name and id become undefined on the elements.  The label behavior now functions the way its supposed to, but only the first rendered checkbox gets its value changed since they all share the same id/for attribute values.  Is there a corresponding change to the component or its template?

Comment: this is correct as well. In many ways it seems like the preferable way to achieve this, as it's much clearer what the intention of these are: binding their value to the template. I overlooked the fact that bound values are always expressions, so you are correct that it would need to be a string or variable value to bind in the way I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?

`<input type="checkbox" name="{{name}}" id="{{id}} /><label for="{{id}}"></label>`

Comment: I just updated my question a few minutes ago.  This doesn't work as Angular will give an error about for not being a known property of the label element.  The solution to that is to use either `[htmlFor]` property or `[attr.for]` attribute binding.